# How to search for a value in a DB field containing a list of values?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I hope I'm asking this question correctly.  I'm using ColdFusion 10 and have a mySQL table named `companies`.  In the table there is a field named `stateList`.  It contains a comma delimited list of state_IDs where the company has stores.

I have a search form for the user to select a state to find the companies in that state.  I need to pass that `form.state_ID` to the search query to see if `companies.stateList` contains `form.state_ID`.

The only code I tried that returned any results, and they were not all correct results, was

```html
<cfquery name="searchCompanies" datasource="#businessDSN#">
  SELECT company_id, company_name, stateList
  FROM companies
  WHERE stateList LIKE "%#form.state_ID#"
</cfquery>
```

If I searched for Arizona, `state_ID` 4, the above query returned any company that had 4, 14, 24, 34, and 44 in its `stateList`.

Is what I want to do possible?  Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... there is a field named stateList. It contains a comma delimited list of state_IDs ...

Oh God, why? If you can, change that to a proper relationship table immediately!

But for the time being...

```html
<cfquery name="searchCompanies" datasource="#businessDSN#">
  SELECT company_id, company_name, stateList
  FROM companies
  WHERE CONCAT(',', stateList, ',') 
        LIKE
        CONCAT('%,', <cfqueryparam value="#form.state_ID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">, ',%')
</cfquery>
```

And, *please* use `<cfqueryparam>` instead of dropping [unchecked user input](http://xkcd.com/327/) into your SQL string.

Comment: +100. Ditto on restructuring. As you discovered, querying lists is awkward, not to mention slow and error prone. Because you must resort to string comparisons, even a single space difference can cause queries to return incorrect results. A more robust structure is to store the relationships in a separate table: CompanyState columns: Company_id, State_id.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the reminder to use cfqueryparam. This is still returning the same results as my original code though.  All IDs in the list with a 4, 14, 24, 34, 40-49 are being returned.

Comment: The code Tomalak provided will **not** return all IDs with a 4 - pay close attention to what is being done with commas.

Comment: I took over this mess last week and have already made some other db changes.  I will create the company_states table and use it.  Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @RobK - FYI: The above query works just fine. Sounds like the changes were not applied (or maybe it is just a simple caching issue).

Comment: @Leigh - You are correct.  I missed the comma after the first %.  Thanks Tomalak and Leigh for your help.  I'm still going to fix this the right way.

Comment: I'm don't work with mysql so I don't know exactly how that function works.  However, it appears that the query will only work if the is items are in the same order.  In other words, if statelist was "3,1,4" and form.state_id was "1,3,4", would the query return the hoped for records?

Comment: @DanBracuk - He is only searching for a single state_id so the issue does not apply.

Comment: If it was needed to check a list of values, the same logic could be moved inside a loop (e.g. `<cfloop index="CurState" list=#form.state_id# >`) with the WHERE change to either AND / OR (depending on whether entire list or any match was needed).

Comment: @Peter in fact, ColdFusion natively supports lists in `cfqueryparam` (for use in SQL `IN`), but that does not work here, unfortunately.

Comment: @RobK - *Re:  I'm still going to fix this the right way* Yeah, normalizing is definitely the way to go. I just wanted to point out the approach above really does work .. in case (heaven forbid) you ever have to work with lists again ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I know about the list attribute. I was responding to Dan's comment regarding comparing lists on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, you can use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)... like:

```
<cfquery name="searchCompanies" datasource="#businessDSN#">
  SELECT company_id, company_name, stateList
  FROM companies
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(<cfqueryparam value="#form.state_ID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,stateList)
</cfquery>
```

I'm not sure if the query is any faster then Tomalak's though.

And yeah, normalize that data!!

Comment: Yep, if you *must* do it, that is another good technique. My guess is performance of the two queries would be similar. Neither would be terribly efficient, as once you start using functions or `like` it tends to prevent the database from utilizing indexes. Just another reason to avoid lists :)